# Python inherit method from arbitrary class

Tags: python, class

I'm sure this will be a duplicate question, but I can't seem to find the words to locate one.

I have a set of very similar models I'd like to code up. The models are all the same, apart from a single function / line of code. I'd like to avoid any code repetition. Let' see an MWE:

```
import numpy as np

class SinModel:   
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi)
    def run(self):
        # Computations which are invariant of the function we use later
        self.y = np.sin(self.x)
        # More computations which are invariant of which funcion was used
```

Our second model will involve the same series of computations, but will use a different function mid way though (here, cosine instead of sine):

```
class CosModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi)
    def run(self):
        # Computations which are the same as in SinModel
        self.y = np.cos(self.x)
        # More computations which are the same as in SinModel
```

Here I have lots of code repetition. Is there a better way to implement these models? I was hoping it would be possible to create a class `Model` which could inherit the differing function from an arbitrary class.

An important note is that the function which changes between models may take different arguments from `self` depending on the model.

Comment: how about a parent model class that has the common portions, and then create all these child classes by inheriting from it?

Comment: To do this wouldn't I have to split my function ```run``` into two parts? Splitting before and after the function I'd like to alter? Then the child classes could have some method which would execute the first half of ```run``` as inherited from the parent, compute the function, and then compute the second half of ```run``` as inherited?

Comment: indeed, that would be a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The words you're looking for are inheritance (allowing a class to inherit and extends / specialize a parent class) and the "template method" design pattern (which is possibly the most common design pattern - the one everyone discovers by itself long before reading about design patterns).

Expanding on your MWE:

```
import numpy as np

class ModelBase(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi)

    def run(self):
        # Computations which are invariant of the function we use later

        self.y = self.compute_y()

        # More computations which are invariant of which funcion was used


    def compute_y(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("class {} must implement compute_y()".format(type(self).__name__))



class SinModel(ModelBase):   
    def compute_y(self):
        return np.sin(self.x)

class CosModel(ModelBase):
    def compute_y(self):
        return np.cos(self.x)
```

This being said, creating instance attributes outside the initializer (the  `__init__` method) is considered bad practice - an object should be fully initialized (have all it's attributes defined) when the initializer returns, so it might be better to move the  `self.y = self.compute_y()` line to the initializer if possible, or, if `self.y` always only depends on `self.x`, make it a computed attribute:

```
class ModelBase(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi)

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._compute_y()

    def _compute_y(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("class {} must implement _compute_y()".format(type(self).__name__))


    def run(self):
        # Computations which are invariant of the function we use later

        # no need to explicitely set self.y here, just use `self.y`
        # and it will delegate to self._compute_y() 
        #(you can't set it anymore anyway since we made it a readonly propery) 

        # More computations which are invariant of which funcion was used



class SinModel(ModelBase):   
    def _compute_y(self):
        return np.sin(self.x)

class CosModel(ModelBase):
    def _compute_y(self):
        return np.cos(self.x)
```

Also at this point you don't necessarily need subclasses anymore, at least if that's the only thing that changes - you can just pass the proper function as a callback to your model class ie:

```
class Model(object):
    def __init__(self, compute_y):
        self.x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi)
        self._compute_y = compute_y

    @property
    def y(self):
        return self._compute_y(self)

    def run(self):
       # code here


cos_model = Model(lambda obj: np.cos(obj.x))
cos_model.run()

sin_model = Model(lambda obj: np.sin(obj.x))
sin_model.run()
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. This answers my question. I'm also pleased you included notes on good / bad practices (though not new to python, I'm new to the more OO approach)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and there's even a name for it: *Inheritance* is the idea that child classes can "inherit" behaviors and attributes from parent classes, and *Polymorphism* is the idea that two child classes, sharing similar behavior, can have different implementations of the same method - so that you can call a method on an object without knowing explicitly what type it is, and still have it do the right thing.

Here's how you'd do that in python:

```
class TrigModel:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = np.linspace(-np.pi, np.pi)
    def run(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Use subclasses SinModel or CosModel")

class SinModel(TrigModel):
    @override
    def run(self):
        self.y = np.sin(self.x)

class CosModel(TrigModel):
    @override
    def run(self):
        self.y = np.cos(self.x)
```

Unless you explicitly specify otherwise (by declaring a method like `run()` that *overrides* the parent class's method of the same name), `SinModel` and `CosModel` will call `TrigModel`'s methods on themselves (in this case, they both call `TrigModel`'s constructor, but then display different behavior when you call `run()` on them).

If you then do:

```
model.run()
```

then `model` will behave differently depending on whether it's a `SinModel` or a `CosModel`, depending on what you set it to beforehand.

The `@override` decorator isn't strictly necessary, but it's good practice to lessen ambiguity.

Comment: There's a bit more to it - as mentionned by the OP, `run()` has a lot of common code before and after the line that computes and set `self.y` and you certainly don't want to copy-paste the whole damn thing just to change one line.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Although you're right, I was able to use this answer (and the idea of overwriting a method) to arrive at the first solution you offered in your solution.

Comment: @Ralph well that's not much of a surprise actually - as I stated in my answer, "template method" is one of the most obvious OO design patterns ;-)